# Transpose specific range to new sheet PasteSpecial Transpose:=True not working

Tags: vba, excel

i want to transpose a specific range of my sheet to another sheet. I therefore have this code:

```
With datasheet
    finalrow = .Cells(.rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim unionRng As Range

    For i = 2 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 25) = duplicate Then '<column 0
            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Range(.Cells(i, 25), .Cells(i, 30))) ' 'P to W
            Else
                Set unionRng = .Range(.Cells(i, 25), .Cells(i, 30))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
    If IsEmpty(reportsheet.Range("J200").End(xlUp)) And reportsheet.Range("J200").End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
        unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("J150")
        unionRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
          False, Transpose:=True
    Else
        unionRng.Copy reportsheet.Range("J200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        unionRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
          False, Transpose:=True
    End If
End If
```

But transposing to the other worksheet to cell J150 insn't working, I always get the Error 1004.

Any ideas what is wrong with my `PasteSpecial Transpose:=True` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is `unionRng` is a range of unified cell selections and you try to paste there with `unionRng.PasteSpecial` but Excel does not support pasting into multiple cell selections.

So you probably meant something like below

```
unionRng.Copy 'copy only and past below
reportsheet.Range("J150").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

The same issue for your other `PasteSpecial`.